# n-variable analogue of Chu-Vandermond identity

Tags: combinatorics

Is there an n-variable generalization of the well known Chu-Vandermond identity, such as 
$$
{{a_1+\cdots +a_m}\choose{k_1+\cdots + k_m}}=\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_m=n} {a_1 \choose k_1}\cdots {a_m \choose k_m}?
$$ 
Does someone know a reference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you probably mean $
{{a_1+\cdots +a_m}\choose{n}}=\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_m=n} {a_1 \choose k_1}\cdots {a_m \choose k_m}
$

Comment: Well yes, since the $k_i$ add to $n$ this is equivalent. So is it true?

Comment: yes with the same proof as the normal version.

Comment: Thanks! Do you may have a reference? Or is it that obvious?

Comment: I was talking about the combinatorial proof. and yes, it is quite obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I will have a look whether there is an analogue closed form for the sum of products of Stirling numbers of the second kind instead of binomial coefficients (without prefactors).